# Implementing Auditting for a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, database, audit

I want to log changes to my MySQL tables. I was thinking I can:

- On app side, insert into auditlog every time I insert/update/delete something
- Alternatively, I can use MySQL triggers to insert into audit log. To determine who (which app user triggered this change I will have a `lastUpdatedBy` column). But how do I do this for DELETEs?

Which is a better way? Or what is the proper/industrial standard?

Comment: Have you checked [hibernate-envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)?

Comment: Did you try this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178213/mysql-audit-and-general-log

Answer (score 0):

Mysql enterprise provides audit plugin which will handle your auditing. check below link

https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/audit.html

Comment: does this require that each application user has 1 DB user too? Is that the recommended way?

Comment: you can refer guidelines and documentation on official website. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/audit-log-filtering.html#audit-log-filtering-enabling-logging it is recommended to use but still it is totally depends up on your current requirement.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement in detail so that I can suggest you more

Comment: I want to be able to know which application user did something. Lets assume its an e commerce app, when user A edit his profile I want an audit log entry. Similarly when an automated system task updates a record for example I want a log entry too. So its not tied to the MySQL user account used to run the query but an application account.